# SQLite .NET, ExecuteScalarAsync<int>, how to know when there was no result?

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite.net

The SQL statement is retrieving the ID of a row. But there may be no such row. When I executed a particular SQL statement in a GUI tool, it returned "0 rows returned in 0ms from:...".

However, when I executed the same SQL statement with `ExecuteScalarAsync<int>`, it returned 0, and no exception or null occurred. How do I know if there was no such row? Theoretically, there can be a row whose ID is 0.

PS:
It is SQLite-net which I added using Nuget (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). Its version is 1.4.118. The SQL statement was very simple one. I changed the field names, but basically it is something like:

```
using SQLite;

public Task<int> GetLastID()
{
    return RealDatabase.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>
        ("SELECT max(ID) FROM DATA)");
}
```

Comment: Maybe use `ExecuteScalarAsync<int?>`?

Comment: It returned `null` when there was no match, but thew an exception when there was a match. The message was: `NotSupportedException: Don't know how to read System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]`

Comment: @DamnVegetables post the code, the query and the full exception in the question itself. Don't post parts of it in the comments

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that exception is a response to the first comment and does not belong in the question. Imo the question is fine without code and OP clearly indicated that there was no exception involved.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis then post an answer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't have the answer, why so grumpy?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis then we do need the code to reproduce the problem and answer it. For example, what `ExecuteScalarAsync<int>`? [ExecuteScalarAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223677(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `Task<object>`. There's no generic version. Should we *google* to find which library has an `ExecuteScalarAsync<T>` ?

Comment: @DamnVegetables ADO.NET's [ExecuteScalarAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223677(v=vs.110).aspx) isn't generic, so it *can* return a null. Which library are you using?

Comment: @DamnVegetables the first relevant result I found is [this](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net) Are you using Xamarin Components instead of ADO.NET ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The title mentions "SQLite.NET" and I can't blame the OP for not knowing there are multiple providers around with that name. Sample code _rarely_ mentions the namespace (and I bet most SQLite.NET clones use the same `System.Data.SQLite`) or reference, so that wouldn't help either. Your last comment was useful, though.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis which is why there's the rule that a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example should be posted. *We* shouldn't have to guess. It's not my opinion anyway. That's one of the reasons to close

Comment: @DamnVegetables are you using [this provider?](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) You are out of luck then, [there's an open issue](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/450) about nullable results for ExecuteScalar that's still open

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree that the question isn't MCVE (only because there happen to be multiple "sqlite.net" providers out there), it's just that your original comments "post code and exception" wouldn't have contributed to the quality of the question, hense my response(s).

Comment: I have added the requested data... and yes, it was the very project. I guess I would have to improvise some workaround.

Comment: Try `ExecuteScalarAsync<object>()` and check for null before casting to int. Or use `IFNULL` in the query to return an "invalid" value, eg -1. Although a NULL is safer in this case - less likely that someone will forget to compare the result against the magic value

Comment: PS - why not use the 0? IDs typically start from 1, so 0 *is* an invalid value.

Comment: Yes, I can avoid ID 0. That is why I said 'theoretically'. I was just curious about how to detect that situation (0 row).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with an extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;

namespace MyApp.DB
{
    public class Row<T>
    {
        public T scalar_value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Maybe<T>
    {
        public readonly T Value;
        public Maybe(T v) { Value = v;  }
    }

    public static class SQLiteExtensions
    {
        public async static Task<Maybe<T>> QueryScalarAsync<T>(this SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection conn, string sql)
        {
            var res = await conn.QueryAsync<Row<T>>(sql);
            if (res.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return new Maybe<T>(res[0].scalar_value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A return value of `null` signifies no rows found and any return value itself is wrapped in a `Maybe` class so that null values can be distinguished:

```
var version = await conn_.QueryScalarAsync<int>("SELECT version AS scalar_value FROM schema_version");
if (version == null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("no rows found");
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("value = {0}", version.Value));
}
```

The only gotcha is that your query must include a column named `scalar_value`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the [provider](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) doesn't have nullable types implemented and there's an [open issue](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/issues/450) about it.

Although can either switch to different provider (please advice if you know lightweight alternative), I use the following hack. In my case I can't simple avoid zero (0) value, it has special meaning in database and I must distinguish it from no data.

```
public Task<int> GetLastID()
{
    var sRes = RealDatabase.ExecuteScalarAsync<string>
        ("SELECT cast(max(ID) as varchar) FROM DATA)");
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(sRes) ? null : int.Parse(sRes);

}
```