# How to handle if ExecuteScalar is null

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I would like your help on how to handle and exception in C# if ExecuteScalar is null. Am trying it but am getting a null reference exceprion. This is my code

```
public async Task<int> SumItemAsync()
{
      Object data = await db.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>("SELECT 
      SUM(Amount) FROM Spent");
      if (data != null)
      {
          return Convert.ToInt32(data);
      }
      else
      {
          return 0;
      }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain more at which point you are getting null error

Comment: `Am trying it but am getting a null reference exceprion.` Please share the **exact** exception details.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157572/sqlite-net-executescalarasyncint-how-to-know-when-there-was-no-result ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually didn't solve it by using your code but you mentioned that my query returns null but I tell ExecuteScalarAsync that is should be an int. So from your statement I did it like this and it worked. Thanks anyway

> public async Task SumItemAsync()
>           {
>
> ```
>         var data = await db.ExecuteScalarAsync<String>("SELECT SUM(TotalAmount) FROM Spent");
>
>         if (data != null)
>         {
>             return data;
>         }
>
>         else
>         {
>             return "0.00";
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is that your query returns `null` but you tell `ExecuteScalarAsync` that is should be an `int`. Change it to a nullable int.

```
var data = db.ExecuteScalarAsync<int?>("SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Spent")
return data ?? 0;
```

You can then simplify the return expression a little bit.

Comment: I actually didn't solve it by using your code but you mentioned that my query returns null but I tell ExecuteScalarAsync that is should be an int. So from your statement I did it like this and it worked.